# discord.py Handle discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

Tags: python, discord.py

im trying to handle this error `discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions`

I know that error appears when the bot is muted by a role in the discord server and the bot try to send a message(on_message) or a command. i just want to make a print in the python terminal something like "Permission error." and not the big error that is written.
i tried with this:

```
from discord.ext.commands import MissingPermissions
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, CommandNotFound):
        return
    elif isinstance(error, (ConversionError, BadArgument)):
        await ctx.send("Respeta el formato del comando :eyes:")
        print("No se respetó el formato del comando ")

        return
    elif isinstance(error, MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("Debes ingresar la cantidad, Ej : *bot blabla 250* :eyes:")
        return
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        print("error de permisos ")
        return 
    if isinstance(error, commands.BotMissingPermissions) and "Missing Permissions" in str(error):
        print("error de permiso")
        return
    if isinstance(exception, commands.MissingPermissions):
        print("Blabla")
        return
    raise error
```

The others errors that i wrote are perfectly handled but i cant with the missingPermissions.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, you're best bet may be to do something like:

```
@commandnamehere.error
async def info_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):
        return
```

What this does it when a specific command gives an error, you can make it do whatever, whether it be print it, send a message to a channel, etc

Also, do note that I have the command in the example above as CommandInvokeError. You'll need to set that to the error you're receiving.

Comment: Thank u, the error isnt in a Command, the error is from the section @client.event
async def on_message(message):

can u make an example with that please?

Comment: Hey, sorry I just saw this. I'm afraid I have less than a single clue on how to do so with events. I'll think hard on it and come back if I find a way

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [client.on_error](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.on_error). So far I've seen, it's triggered when there is an error during events like on_message.